# Traducción de código C a MIPS

Tags: c, ensamblador, registro, mips32

intento traducir un trozo de código de C a MIPS, el código en C es el siguiente:

```
int x = 1;
int y = -1;
int z = x+y
if (z == 0) {
    y++;
} else if (z == 1) {
    y--;
} else {
    y = 100;
}
```

Estoy comenzando con todo esto de lenguaje ensamblador, todavía no logro encontrar la solución al problema que tengo, lo que he logrado hasta el momento es lo siguiente (realizado en MARS):

```
addi $t3, $zero, 1         #int x = 1;
    sub $t4, $zero, $t3    #int y = -1;
    add $t5, $t3, $t4      #int z = x+y
    bne $t5, $zero, FirstELSE
    addi $t4, $t4, 1
    
    FirstELSE:
        beq $t5, $t3, SecondELSE
        sub $t4, $t4, $t3
    
    SecondELSE:
        addi $t4, $zero, 100
```

El problema es que el secondELSE parece ejecutarse sin importar el valor de z (z representado por el registro $t5) Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ejecución en esamblador es secuencial a menos que haya una instrucción de salto. Tras la instrucción `sub $t4, $t4, $t3` se proseguirá por la instrucción siguiente, que es la `addi $t4, $zero, 100` sin que importe que lleve o no una etiqueta (pues las etiquetas desaparecen al ensamblar).

En definitiva, tienes que saltar (incondicionalmente) al terminar el bloque `FirstELSE` más allá de la instrucción `SecondELSE`, para lo que necesitarás otra etiqueta:

```
    addi $t3, $zero, 1     #int x = 1;
    sub $t4, $zero, $t3    #int y = -1;
    add $t5, $t3, $t4      #int z = x+y
    bne $t5, $zero, FirstELSE
    addi $t4, $t4, 1
    
FirstELSE:
    beq $t5, $t3, SecondELSE
    sub $t4, $t4, $t3
    j EndIF

SecondELSE:
    addi $t4, $zero, 100

EndIF:
    ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esto me ha ayudado a resolver mi problema

Answer (score 1):

Para este y para futuros problemas, podés comparar tu traducción directamente con el código ensamblador producido por el compilador (que me parece lo más sensato).

Podés usar tu sistema y hacer "cross compiling", es decir, una compilación cruzada. Para esto podés usar tu compilador de preferencia. **Clang** puede hacer compilación cruzada con la opción `-target`, pero tiene algunas otras limitaciones, te voy a exponer cómo hacerlo con **GCC**. Ambos casos están en [este link de MIPSym en github](https://mipsym.github.io/mipsym/CrossCompile.html). Siempre que hagas esto podés usar el inline assembly de C para introducir comentarios en el ensamblador generado. El ensamblador generado depende mucho de las opciones de compilación:

## Instalar GCC

En ubuntu/debian, el paquete es normalmente `gcc-mips-linux-gnu`:

```sh
apt install gcc-mips-linux-gnu g++-mips-linux-gnu
```

Necesitas privilegios, ya sea ser root o usar sudo. Yo siempre prefiero deshabilitar sudo, así que en mi caso es como root.

## Compilar para MIPS generando ensamblador

El comando instalado es `mips-linux-gnu-gcc`. Podés compilar para MIPS con:

```sh
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -O3 -S -mfp32 -march=R2000 archivo-de-codigo.c
```

Sería:

- **-O3**: Mayor nivel de optimización para velocidad en GCC.
- **-S**: Generar ensamblador (no ensamblar).
- **-mfp32**: Usar registros floating point de 32 bits.
- **-march=R2000**: El procesador de destino (MIPS 1, R2000).

## Examinar el código

El ensamblador generado tiene la sintaxis AT&T. Se puede generar con sintaxis INTEL usando `-masm=intel`, pero no se cómo funcionará esto con el cross-compiler a MIPS.